# allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level error, but it IS an application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, web-config

When trying to build my website in Visual Studio 2010, I receive the following error:

*It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\ussvision\knowledgebase\web.config 20*

I have a web.config in my root - /ussvision/ - and another web.config in a subdirectory - /knowledgebase/.

I know this error usually means you haven't configured your subdirectory as an application in IIS7.  **But I have!**  I opened up IIS7, right-clicked OWNER-PC, clicked "Add Website", pointed to the physical path, right-clicked knowledgebase, and selected "convert to application".  When trying to build, it continues to give me this error, pointing to the web.config in my knowledgebase subdirectory.  Should I have done this in IIS7 differently?

Any guidance to eliminate this error so I can build the site would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post web.config especially around line 20? Do you have a membershipprovider login redirect page there?

Comment: Sure.  Thanks for responding.  I removed my lines 20-23, and then it pointed to line 58, which is <roleManager>, but anyway, so I'm not sure.  But anyway, here is my line 20 on web.config:     <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".YAFNET_Authentication" protection="All" timeout="43200" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
    </authentication>

Comment: as I guess, there is authantication mode there, can you try to change that line 20-23 to <authentication mode="None" />

Comment: Hi Nesim.  I did, and VS still gives me the same error.  YAFNET_Authentication .... YAF stands for yetanotherforum, which is the /knowledgebase/ I downloaded from their website and I'm trying to impliment.  Thanks again for your help!